# What's the way to pick images from gallery on Android in 2018?

Tags: android, image, android-library

i would like to know the community opinion on the problem of getting image on Android from common sources to use in our App. 
I know that there are questions back to 2010's about it on stack overflow, but i found the answers a bit to much boilerplate code for this simple task.

Maybe anyone knows some lightweight library to get image from gallery (or other common sources) so code can stay simple and readable

maybe something like:

```
            Bitmap image;

            SomeCoolLib.
            .performImageSelect()
            .asBitmap()  
            .listener(new RequestListener<String, Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onCancel() {
                    return false;
                }
            }).into(image);
```

to let user:

[image: so we can see this]

Comment: "Maybe anyone knows some lightweight library" -- asking for off-site resources is considered to be off-topic for Stack Overflow. There are entire sites, such as [the Android Arsenal](http://android-arsenal.com/), dedicated to cataloging libraries.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, but unfortunately I can't ask there for "best practice"

Comment: A good practice is to use the Android Storage Access Framework instead (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html). No libraries required.

Comment: @AlessandroCrugnola maybe you could add answer with some code samples i think it will be very helpful for me and other junior developers, who will have the same issue :)

Comment: if (year==2018) pick images;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use the Android Storage Access Framework (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html).

For instance, in your activity you can request to the device and type of document (notice the **intent.setType** method, if you want to filter by document type).

This code will open the android document picker and let user to pick an image:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int OPEN_DOCUMENT_CODE = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton).setOnClickListener(view ->    {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_DOCUMENT_CODE);
        });

    }
}
```

Then, just implement the **onActivityResult** in the very same activity, in order to receive the image selected:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    if (requestCode == OPEN_DOCUMENT_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (resultData != null) {
            // this is the image selected by the user
            Uri imageUri = resultData.getData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this way you won't be able to get the file. What can I do with the URI to get an actual file ?

Comment: This intent is not showing any dialog, just opens directly gallery. Do you know why?

Comment: @BoldijarPaul If you use KTX, just do uri.toFile()

Answer (score 2):

### 1, Pick a image

If u use this(**Old style**):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
```

Or this(**Official recommendation**):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("image/*");
```

Those code will open FileManager in Android 8, that's difficult to use.

If u want to open the albums app in user's device and pick a photo, u should use this(**I recommendation**):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

All those way before will get an Uri in `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)`.

### 2, Handle the Uri

Sometimes we need the image's real path, u should use those code:

```
@Nullable
public static String getImagePathFromUri(@Nullable Uri aUri) {
    String imagePath = null;
    if (aUri == null) {
        return imagePath;
    }
    if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(ApplicationContext.get(), aUri)) {
        String documentId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(aUri);
        if ("com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(aUri.getAuthority())) {
            String id = documentId.split(":")[1];
            String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=" + id;
            imagePath = getImagePath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, selection);
        } else if ("com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(aUri.getAuthority())) {
            Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                    Long.valueOf(documentId));
            imagePath = getImagePath(contentUri, null);
        }
    } else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(aUri.getScheme())) {
        imagePath = MediaUtils.getImagePath(aUri, null);
    } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(aUri.getScheme())) {
        imagePath = aUri.getPath();
    }
    return imagePath;
}

private static String getImagePath(Uri aUri, String aSelection) {
    String path = null;
    Cursor cursor = ApplicationContext.get()
            .getContentResolver()
            .query(aUri, null, aSelection, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return path;
}
```

Comment: what is MediaUtils here in  MediaUtils.getImagePath(aUri, null)? Cannot find any imports

Comment: @SharukhMohammed its the second function